# How can I test if gunicorn is working and communicating with nginx?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm deploying my first attempt at using django+gunicorn+nginx.

- I have django working (`curl -XGET http://127.0.0.0.1:8000` works fine if I run the development server).
- I have nginx working for static content (for example I can retrieve `http://example.com/static/my_pic.png` in my browser).
- I'm not getting any wsgi content from my website, and I haven't been able to find a good troubleshooting guide (does it just work for everyone else?!). I start gunicorn using supervisor, which reports that it is indeed running:

(in shell:)

```
supervisorctl status my_app
my_app                   RUNNING    pid 1002, uptime 0:29:51
```

Here's the boilerplate script I used to start it:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script variables
NAME="gunicorn_myapp"                      # Name of process
DJANGODIR=/webapps/www/my_project          # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/webapps/www/run/gunicorn.sock    # communicte using this socket
USER=app_user                              # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                              # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings # settings file
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=my_project.wsgi         # WSGI module name

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

Here's the (condensed) nginx config file:

```
upstream my_server {
  server unix:/webapps/www/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=10s;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name example.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    access_log /webapps/www/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/www/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /webapps/www/my_project/my_app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /webapps/www/my_project/my_app/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://my_server;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://example.com;
            break;
        }
    }

    location  /robots.txt {
        alias /webapps/www/my_project/my_app/static/robots.txt ;
    }
    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /webapps/www/my_project/my_app/static/;
    }
}
```

So: gunicorn is running, nginx is running ... what tests (and how?) should I perform to determine if gunicorn is doing the wsgi stuff properly (and if nginx is proxying the said stuff through correctly)?

Edit: I've narrowed the problem down to the communication between gunicorn and nginx via the unix socket. If I change the $SOCKFILE to be bound to `0.0.0.0:80` and stop nginx, then the app's pages are served from my website. The bad news is that the socket file strings are exactly the same between the two conf files, so I don't know why they aren't communicating. I suppose this means nginx isn't correctly fetching and passing the data through then?

Comment: Well, you tell by seeing if it serves your site, which you say it doesn't. Where is the part of the nginx configuration where you tell it to proxy through the $SOCKFILE socket?

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I've added the nginx config file (comments removed). The proxy_pass entry is there now. Thanks enormously btw for your answers on SE - they've helped solve most of my django problems over the past month.

Comment: Daniel, at your suggestion I've had a go at debugging what's going on with the socket. I've edited with more info; I hope it's useful.

Comment: Does the user nginx is running as have access to the directory the socket is in? Does it work if you change it to /tmp? Is there anything in the nginx error log?

Comment: The directory with the socket is 755, but when I change the socket location to `/tmp/gunicorn.sock` (777) after restarting nginx and gunicorn it doesn't make a difference (I though that would be it because no write access for nginx). The log files don't help me much: gunicorn is started as `app_user`, and the nginx-error.log shows when I try to get the /login/ url: `765 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: example.com, request: "GET /login HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/login", host: "example.com".`

Comment: (Forgot to mention, the socket file itself is `srwxrwxrwx`)

Answer (score 4):

Go to project directory :

```
cd projectname
gunicorn --log-file=- projectname.wsgi:application
```

and

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

Comment: Please explain what the commands do and why someone would execute them to resolve the issue.

Comment: @marchWest `cd` changes your directory. `guicorn --log...` runs your python application called in this case `projectname.wsgi:application`. `systemctl status gunicorn` gives you the status of the process.

Comment: @santhosh_dj systemctl command fails to run inside docker with following error `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "systemctl": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown\r\n`

Comment: @saurbh, Your output shows that executing inside the docker. I executed the cmd not inside the docker. I am not familiar with this.

Comment: @santhosh_dj Yeah. Examining the output of `ps aux` on the docker container helped to figure whether the gunicorn process is running or not.