# How to run shell command after gunicorn service? this is for docker enterypoint.sh file

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, gunicorn

Below is my docker enterypoint.sh file code

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

python3 test1.py

gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 "app:app" --workers=1 --threads=10 --timeout=3600

node /home/test2.js
```

I want to run test2.js nodejs app after gunicorn service starts because test2.js required to connect with localhost:8000. Please help me with a solution for this

Comment: May I suggest thta you replace the (unnecessary) _sh_ tag by a _gunicorn_ tag? Your questions seemst to be mostly relevant to _gunicorn_. Perhaps the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543145/how-can-i-test-if-gunicorn-is-working-and-communicating-with-nginx) question can help you?

Comment: You'd almost always use a separate container for this.  Are the `test1.py` and `test2.js` files part of a larger integration test sequence?  I might consider running the `gunicorn` process (only) as the main container process (directly as the image `CMD`, not via a script), and then running the integration test from the host outside a container.

Comment: Without debugging details, it's hard to tell what exactly is wrong. If you run this with `bash -x`, does it get all the way to the `node` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think the ideal solution will be to deploy 2 different containers using docker-compose, one for gunicorn and another one for test2.js nodejs app.

But could run test2.js nodejs script after starting gunicorn service using below code by inserting "&" at the end of gunicorn line

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

python3 test1.py

gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 "app:app" --workers=1 --threads=10 --timeout=3600 &

node /home/test2.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

python3 test1.py

# wait 10 seconds, then run test2.js
{ sleep 10; node /home/test2.js; } &

gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 "app:app" --workers=1 --threads=10 --timeout=3600
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the next line is only executed after the previous one, but maybe the command ends before the port is active, so you can use a *while* to check that

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

python3 test1.py

gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 "app:app" --workers=1 --threads=10 --timeout=3600
#
check=1
#
while [ $check -eq 1 ]
do
  echo "Testing"
  test=$(netstat -nlt | grep "0.0.0.0:8000" &> /dev/null)
  check=$?
  sleep 2
done

node /home/test2.js
```